# Showing elements form a Matrix that is Unimodular

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Every subgroup $H$ of a free abelian group $G$ of rank $n$ is free of rank $s \leq n$. Moreover there exists a basis $u_1, ... , u_n$ for $G$ and
positive integers $\alpha_1, ... ,\alpha_s$ such that $\alpha_1 u_1, ... , \alpha_s u_s$ is a basis for $H$.

This is  Theorem 1.16. in the book Algebraic-Number Theory by Ian Stewart and David Tall, on page 29. The first part of the proof is -

[image]

In the proof it is written that -

> From all such coefficients, let, $\lambda(w_1 , ... , w_n)$ be the least positive integer occurring.

and

> $u_1, w_2, ... , w_n$ is another basis for $G$. (The appropriate matrix is clearly unimodular.)

**QUESTION**

1. What is the meaning of "$\lambda(w_1 , ... , w_n)$ be the least positive integer occurring"? i.e. what is $\lambda(w_1 , ... , w_n)$?
2. How to show that the appropriate matrix of $u_1, w_2, ... , w_n$ is unimodular? Plz show the derivation, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question: $\lambda(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ is equal to the minimum element of the set of positive coefficients, i.e. $\min\{h_i : 1 \leq i \leq n, h_i > 0\}$.

Regarding the second question: the associated matrix is
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&\cdots && 0\\
q_2 &1&\ddots&&\vdots\\
q_3 & 0 & \ddots&0&0\\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
q_n & 0 & \cdots &0& 1}.
$$
There are many ways to see that this matrix is unimodular. One is to note first that the matrix is lower triangular.

Comment: The determinant of a lower triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries, thus the matrix is unimodular, that is okay but I am  having trouble how you got the associated matrix, it looks like you just filled the first column with the coefficients of the equation $u_1=w_1+ \cdots$ which I could not understand .... could u  spell out in detail how you got the associated matrix please?

Comment: Generally I am used to see a $n \times n$ matrix filled with coefficients, for example look at the matrix $A$ in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794121/how-does-deta-neq-0-imply-linearly-independence-of-y-i

Comment: @Andrew as your linked post says, we want $a_{ij}$ for which $y_i = \sum a_{ij}x_j$. In this case, we have $y_i = w_i$ for all $i$ and $x_1 = u_1, x_i = w_i$ for $i \geq 2$. For these *specific* choices of vectors, determine what the $a_{ij}$ must be.

Comment: Are sure$ y_i = w_i$? you later defined $x_1 = u_1, x_i = w_i$...plz reply.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I am sure. The point is that we simply have $x_i = y_i$ for $i \geq 2$. In other words, for $j \geq 2$, $a_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: To verify the appropriate matrix we do the following calculation:
$$(c_{ij})(x_j)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\cdots && 0\\
q_2 &1&\ddots&&\vdots\\
q_3 & 0 & \ddots&0&0\\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
q_n & 0 & \cdots &0& 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
\vdots \\
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \cdot x_{1} \\
q_2\cdot x_{1}+1 \cdot x_{2} \\
q_3\cdot x_{1}+1 \cdot x_{3} \\
\vdots \\
q_n\cdot x_{1}+1 \cdot x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
u_{1} \\
w_{2} \\
w_{3} \\
\vdots \\
w_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$ **Is it correct?**

Comment: I don’t see why anything needs to be verified and I find the usage of vectors as entries for a column vector suspicious, but yes: that is a thing you can write

Comment: $u_1=w_1+q_2 w_2+ \cdots q_n w_n \implies x_1 = x_1(q_2+q_3+ \cdots q_n) + x_2+x_3 \cdots x_n \implies 0 = x_1(-1+q_2+q_3+ \cdots q_n) + x_2+x_3 \cdots x_n$. If $(-1+q_2+q_3+ \cdots q_n)=0 $ then the set $\{ x_2, x_3 \cdots x_n \}$ is not a basis by definition of basis since $0 = x_2+x_3 \cdots x_n$ means one of the element of $\{ x_2, x_3 \cdots x_n \}$ is depended on others. If $(-1+q_2+q_3+ \cdots q_n)\neq 0 $ then the set $\{ x_1, x_2, x_3 \cdots x_n \}$ is not a basis in similar way, **it means,** if what you said is right then, $(x_j)$ is not a basis which is against the hypothesis.